# Set notification if is two product category in cart

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to set notifications when I have products from these two different categories inside the card in `WooCommerce`.

This is the code which I using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );
function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) &&
             has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly if I only set one category, but when I set two categories, for some reason I don't have results nor errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly, I thought about that :

(but it's not my best! Maybe I'll come rewrite a more thoughtful code sometimes but for now, this code'll work)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );
function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat1_in_cart = false;
    $cat2_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat1_in_cart = true;
        } elseif(has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )){
            $cat2_in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    if ($cat1_in_cart === true && $cat2_in_cart === true) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I've just a re-edited a bit your code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );
function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat1_in_cart = false;
    $cat2_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat1_in_cart = true;
        } elseif(has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )){
            $cat2_in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    if ($cat1_in_cart === true && $cat2_in_cart === true) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, could you indicate that my solution helped you by marking it with the green check and not republishing my solution?

Comment: @Sam First re-edit your code so he could work. Switch `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details` with `woocommerce_before_cart` and correct the typos inside the code, and I will for sure.

Comment: Yes! Sorry bro! I am dyslexic haha! I looked and re-watch and I never realized this change! Sorry!